# Undefined control sequence when using arrayrulecolor

Tags: errors, color, arrays

When attempting to use `\arrayrulecolor` I get the error:

```
Undefined control sequence. \arrayrulecolor
```

The markup I am using is:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkjunglegreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.26, 0.15}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[
top    = 0.608cm,
bottom = 1.1cm,
left   = 1.20cm,
right  = 1.10cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\makeatletter 
\newcommand\semiLarge{\@setfontsize\semiLarge{13.22}{17.38}}
\makeatother
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}
{1em}{}[\color{darkjunglegreen}{\titlerule[2pt]}]
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{1pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-3pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\begin{document}
\sloppy 
\section*{Section Heading}
\arrayrulecolor{darkjunglegreen}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{3}{C{0.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}}
\large\textbf{Term} & \large\textbf{Word} & \large\textbf{Phrase}\\
\cmidrule[2pt](r){1-1} \cmidrule[1pt](lr){2-2} \cmidrule[1pt](l){3-3}
\end{tabular*}  
\end{document}
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: Load `xcolor` with option `[table]` so that it loads `colortbl`.

Comment: @Bernard, just tried that and the error remains

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excuse for my delay but I have put this code after the comments. I have put into your code only `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[table,RGB]{xcolor}` and all your code works correctly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\usepackage[table,RGB]{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkjunglegreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.26, 0.15}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[
top    = 0.608cm,
bottom = 1.1cm,
left   = 1.20cm,
right  = 1.10cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\makeatletter 
\newcommand\semiLarge{\@setfontsize\semiLarge{13.22}{17.38}}
\makeatother
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}
{1em}{}[\color{darkjunglegreen}{\titlerule[2pt]}]
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{1pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-3pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\begin{document}
\sloppy 
\section*{Section Heading}
\arrayrulecolor{darkjunglegreen}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{3}{C{0.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}}
\large\textbf{Term} & \large\textbf{Word} & \large\textbf{Phrase}\\
\cmidrule[2pt](r){1-1} \cmidrule[1pt](lr){2-2} \cmidrule[1pt](l){3-3}
\end{tabular*}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! perfect!